# Given an Xml document, how would you populate a list of paths of attributes and elements

Tags: c#, xml

Given the following Xml:

```
<Student number='2020'>
  <Subject>Comp</Subject>
  <Credintials>
    <Password>010101</Password>
    <PasswordLength>6</PasswordLength>
    <Contact>contact@example.com</Contact>
  </Credintials>
  <PersonalDetails age='30' height='2'/>
  <Lecture age='30' height='2'>
    <StudentName>Hakeem</StudentName>
  </Lecture>
</Student>
```

I would want to print out the following list:

```
Student.@number=2020
Student.Subject=Comp
Student.Credintials.Password=010101
Student.Credintials.PasswordLength=6
Student.Credintials.Contact=contact@example.com
Student.PersonalDetails.@age=30
Student.Lecture.@age=30
Student.PersonalDetails.@height=2
Student.Lecture.@height=2
Student.Lecture.StudentName=Hakeem
```

I am basically trying to get these paths for attributes and elements which have their values equal to the innerText, elements like StudentName, Password, Subject. atttributes like age, height etc

Thanks

Comment: Tried Xml Serialization ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you read up on [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Have you done a search on SO regarding how to create XML classes from a given XML? ([Example answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26633029/3864353))

Comment: I'd use LINQ to XML, personally... get all the elements using `Descendants`, and then write all the lines for that element.

Comment: Flattening hierarchy? Sounds easy: parse xml, go recursively through elements, generate output for each value and attribute.

Comment: P.S. 'Credentials' is misspelled throughout your code. :p

Comment: I would use serialization personally.  Create an object that represents what the XML should populate. Serialize it to that object.

I have a very small example on the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789111/how-to-create-and-export-data-to-an-xml-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method like this will print out what you expect

```
var xml  = @"<Student number='2020'>
                          <Subject>Comp</Subject>
                          <Credintials>
                            <Password>010101</Password>
                            <PasswordLength>6</PasswordLength>
                            <Contact>contact@example.com</Contact>
                          </Credintials>
                          <PersonalDetails age='30' height='2'/>
                          <Lecture age='30' height='2'>
                            <StudentName>Hakeem</StudentName>
                          </Lecture>
                        </Student>";

var xmlParsed = XElement.Parse(xml);
GetNodeDescendantsAndPrint(xmlParsed);


public void GetNodeDescendantsAndPrint(XElement node, string nameToAppend= null)
{
    var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameToAppend) 
                        ? node.Name.LocalName  
                        : nameToAppend;
    foreach (var att in node.Attributes())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + ".@" + att.Name.LocalName + "=" + att.Value);
    }
    var descendants = node.Elements();
    if (descendants.Any())
    {
        foreach (var innerNode in descendants.OfType<XElement>())
        {
            GetNodeDescendantsAndPrint(innerNode, 
                                        name+"." + innerNode.Name.LocalName );
        }
    }
    else
    {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + node.Value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just some little bugs which i think i can sort out, but great idea , i liked it

Comment: yeah I might be printing out in one or 2 scenarios where I shouldn't, but at least you have an idea on how to continue. :)